# Crear una consulta 3 tablas MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[image: Consulta MYSQL]

TENGO UNA CONSULTA LA CUAL QUIERO QUE SE MUESTRE, LA REALIZO PERO NO ME SALEN LOS DATOS, ESTOY EN ALGO MAL? NECESITO ASESORÍA

```
SELECT pr.nom_producto, det.cantidad, em.nom_empleado,en.fecha_entrada,en.hora_entrada FROM t_detalle_producto_entrada as det
                          INNER JOIN t_producto as pr on pr.id_producto=det.id_producto
                          INNER JOIN t_entrada as en on en.id_entrada= det.id_entrada
                          INNER JOIN t_empleado as em on em.id_empleado = det.id_entrada
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, tienes un simple error, la última línea debería ser

```
INNER JOIN t_empleado as em on em.id_empleado = en.id_empleado
```

Y quedaría así:

```
SELECT pr.nom_producto, det.cantidad, em.nom_empleado,en.fecha_entrada,en.hora_entrada
FROM t_detalle_producto_entrada as det
INNER JOIN t_producto as pr on pr.id_producto=det.id_producto
INNER JOIN t_entrada as en on en.id_entrada= det.id_entrada
INNER JOIN t_empleado as em on em.id_empleado = en.id_empleado
```

Comment: Roger Torne eres genial ! gracias mi amigo

Comment: Carlos, publicaste 2 veces el mismo comentario... Al menos elimina 1. Y si la respuesta que te ofrecieron es la que buscas por favor dala como respondida

Comment: @CarlosPilcoGarcía ¿solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: Tema cerrado gracias, ya marque